# Is there a way to cache intermediate results in Athena

Tags: sql, caching, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

I'm using Athena and my queries all have the same base query, selecting from specific partitions (mainly based on time), filtering out the relevant columns, extracting some data from json strings and doing some data reformatting, in this step I scan ~100 Gb and the resulting table is much smaller ~200 Mb.

On top of the base query I'll have approximately 20-30 different queries, doing different aggregations and data manipulations.

I would like the first query (which will be the base query + some manipulations on the result of the base) to scan all the data and cache the base query results. Then all the following queries will query the cache instead of the original data, this will save me both a lot of time and a lot of money.

Is there a way to tell Athena to cache the results of the base query, or do I need to run the base query separately, save the result and then query it?

If it makes any difference, I'm planning to save the base query as a view, and have all the different queries will run against that view from quickSight.

Answer (score 1):

Since the end  of 2022 Athena allows caching the results (requires Athena engine version 3) on per query basis. Check out the following articles/docs:

- [Amazon Athena announces Query Result Reuse to accelerate queries](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/11/amazon-athena-query-result-reuse-accelerate-queries/)
- [Reusing query results](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/reusing-query-results.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTAS (Create Table as) syntax.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table-as.html

For e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE "db"."tbl_name"
WITH (format = 'textfile', external_location = 's3://bucket_name/folder_name/', field_delimiter='|')
AS select base_query
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to avoid creating a new table, as I need something more dynamic that will update as new data comes in, but maybe that is the way to go.